# Migrating from swift 3 to swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project migrating from Swift 3 to 4.
I fixed all the issues except this one. First at all I don't understand this code :

```
let messageText = stride(from: 0, to: lineNumber, by: 1).reduce("") { "\n\($0.0)" }
```

Reduce function has changed between these two versions. So I want to re-write it to Swift 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the purpose is to create a string with the numbers from
0 (inclusive) to `lineNumber` (exclusive), separated by newline characters, then it should be

```
let messageText = stride(from: 0, to: lineNumber, by: 1).reduce("") { "\($0)\n\($1)" }
```

The error message is misleading, the real problem is that the closure 
has the wrong type, it must take two arguments.

The same can be achieved with

```
let messageText = (0..<lineNumber).map(String.init).joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, 
The "(0..<lineNumber)" return a Range<CGFloat>, it's not working as written :)
I'm using this : stride(from: 0, to: lineNumber, by: 1).map(String.init).joined(separator: "\n")

I've to test it :)

Comment: @Clem166: Well, I assumed that `lineNumber` is an integer – and then the code works: I tested it before posting the answer. If you really need it as a CGFloat then the first version should still work. Or use the second version with `(0..<Int(lineNumber))`

Comment: Working ! Thanks ;)